# Google Maps API v3: Why are there inconsistencies between my search results by Google Maps API V3 and Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm working with a custom map application that uses Google Maps API v3. There are a few problems that I'm encountering.

I'm using the places library to do a search nearby the center of my map with a large radius with a keyword.

Problem 1: When I do a search for "Home Depot" without quotes, I get results for 'Home' or 'Depot', so realtors come back, a dentist named "Dental Depot" is returned, and so on. This doesn't happen in Google Maps itself, however. They manage to only return Home Depots without the need to add quotes. This problem is, of course, solved by adding quotes into my keyword used for the request, but I do not think my users will necessarily know to add quotes. My problem is that Google Maps knows to only return Home Depots by default, why doesn't their API?

Problem 2: Other times, places are not found at all. There is a pizza restaurant called "The Wedge" and searching 'wedge' returns no results at all, but searching 'wedge' over my city in google maps returns four points of interest, both restaurants and two Targets.

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences

Comment: @JoachimRohde My question isn't about geocoding, which is the conversion from address into lat/long coordinates. I'm not getting a response at all for a search for a restaurant called "The wedge", but google maps gets four results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were a few reasons for the discrepancy between what I received using my searches and what I received when performing the same search using google maps itself.

1. Google doesn't use the exact same requests that their map API does, from what I've gathered.
2. I believe they employ a bit of cleverness around popularly searched terms and places. e.g. searching 'Home Depot' without quotes returns only Home Depots, not Dental Depot, Oil Depot, Home Cleaning Solutions, etc. Because after millions of people have searched that, they only want Home Depot. This result is not reflected in the results of their API.

To work around this, I am doubling the amount of requests I make. First, I make a `keyword` `nearbySearch`, then I make a `name` `nearbySearch`. This returns more results of course, and some are irrelevant, but overall, it's a much nicer array of results that with one of the two. For completeness' sake, this literally looks like:

```
request = {
  keyword: keyword,
  bounds: bounds
}

service.nearbySearch(request, searchHandler);


request = {
  name: keyword,
  bounds: bounds
}

service.nearbySearch(request, searchHandler);
```

Where I've already declared `request`,`keyword`, `bounds`, `service`, and the `searchHandler` callback.

If you're struggling to get what you want from a search, try doubling up the requests like this and I hope it works for you.